# DATETIME Format issue in VB.Net with MS Access database when using SQL statements

Tags: ms-access, vb.net-2010, ms-access-2003

I am using vb.net and ms access 2003 as backend. I am not getting any records in my result when I'm using the  sql query  shown below. I'm trying to find records with a date lower (or coming before) the current date.

```
Dim Sql, CurrentDate as String

Dim TrDate as Date

Dim DataVal As Integer

TrDate=DateTime.Now

CurrentDate=Format(TrDate, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")

Sql="Select count(*) from Table1 where InvDate<=#" & CurrentDate & "#"

IF DBConOpen()=True

        cmdOledb.CommandText = sql
         cmdOledb.CommandType = CommandType.Text
         cmdOledb.Connection = ConOledb
         DataVal = cmdOledb.ExecuteScalar
         msgbox(DataVal)

End IF
```

For example if my current date is 01/09/2012 or 02/09/2012 or .. 12/09/2012 and the date in database is 01/09/2012 or 02/09/2012 or .. 12/09/2012. I should get the respective record count. But in this case im getting 0 records.

But if my current date is 01/09/2012 or 02/09/2012 or .. 12/09/2012 and the date in database is 20/08/2012 or 15/06/2012 or .. 30/05/2012. I am getting the correct record count.

The date format I defined in MS access table is 'General Date'. Is anyone able to spot what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
CurrentDate=Format(TrDate, "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt")
```

Access needs an unambiguous date.

You might like to remove the time element as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to determine your Date/Time value in Dot.Net before submitting the query, you could make use of the Access db engine's `Now()` function.

```
Sql="Select count(*) from Table1 where InvDate<=Now()"
```

That approach avoids issues about formatting and delimiters.

If you want just the date without the current time, use `Date()` instead of `Now()`.  (Actually, `Date()` will return midnight as the time component.)